# Поиск в списке элемента типа "Словарь"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, dict

Имеется задача:

Напишите код, который считает количество элементов в заданном списке до тех пор, пока не встретится элемент типа словарь.

Пример:

для списка `[3, "Вася", 0.45, 5, {'диван' : 2, 'слоники' : 9}, "мурзик", 34]` на выходе должны получить число 4

Список для работы:

```
list = [39, 0.24, 3 + 3j, "Иван", 0.45, (8, 9), "кот", {"Камень": 3, 'Дерево':5}, 111]
```

Попытался решить так:

```
l = [39, 0.24, 3 + 3j, "Иван", 0.45, (8, 9), "кот", {"Камень": 3, 'Дерево':5}, 111]
x = len(l)
for i in range(x):
  while l[i] == type(dict):
    print(i)
    break
```

Но, конечно же, условие цикла while неверное :)
Пробовал заменить на такие варианты `while l[i] == {}`, ну и подобные, но как понимаете- безрезультатно :)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить наличие в списке словаря?

Comment: ```if type(l[i]) == dict: print(l[i]) ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваш код имеет неверный алгоритм решения, а также само условие проверки на встречу с `dict`.

Нужно перебрать по очереди все элементы. Так зачем вам в каждой итерации новый цикл `while`? Нужна лишь одна проверка `if`.

Ваше предположение о проверке также неверно. Условие `l[i] == type(dict)` не будет работать. Потому что `type(dict)` будет всегда возвращать `type`. Проверьте сами:

```
print(type(dict))
print(type(int))
print(type(list))
# <class 'type'>
# <class 'type'>
# <class 'type'>
```

Плюс к этому вы пытаетесь сравнить **значение** `l[i]` с **типом** `<class 'type'>`.

Корректная проверка выглядит так `type(l[i]) is dict` или `type(l[i]) == dict` То есть является ли **тип** `l[i]` **типом** `dict`.

Кроме того, рекомендую отказаться от однобуквенных имен. Если к `i` в качестве индекса нет вопросов, то близкое по написанию `l` здесь излишне.

Итоговое решение без подсчета количества.

```
items = [39, 0.24, 3 + 3j, "Иван", 0.45, (8, 9), "кот", {"Камень": 3, 'Дерево':5}, 111]

for i in range(len(items)):
    if type(items[i]) == dict:
        break
    print(items[i])

# 9
# 0.24
# (3+3j)
# Иван
# 0.45
# (8, 9)
# кот
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Вам не нужно использовать цикл `while`, так как вы имеете конечно число входных данных.
   => достаточно цикла `for`
2. В отличие от `type()`, функция `isinstance()` специально создана для проверки принадлежности данных определенному классу (типу данных).
   => используйте встроенную функцию `isinstance()`.
3. На выходе вы должны получить одно единственное значение.
   => Функция `print()`, выводящая количество элементов ДО словаря, должна быть после выполнения цикла.

```
count = 0
for item in mylist:
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        break

    count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import takewhile


data = [39, 0.24, 3 + 3j, "Иван", 0.45, (8, 9), "кот", {"Камень": 3, 'Дерево':5}, 111]

res = len(list(takewhile(lambda x: not isinstance(x, dict), data)))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Чуть иначе можно получить результат так

```
>>> [idx for idx, v in enumerate(lst) if isinstance(v,dict)].pop(0)
7
```